# Flask everytime I refresh the value switches between previous and current ones

Tags: python, flask, request

I made a simple scoreboard with Flask.
When I deployed it with pre-made nginx/uwsgi image([uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker)), I noticed that when I change the value(in this context score) it gets changed inside server. However, when I make a request several times it gave me previous value randomly.
What could be wrong?

Here's the code, thanks in advance

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def api_users():
    return {
               "message": "success",
               "data": [
                   user.get_information() for user in USERS.values()
               ]
           }, 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a request directly to flask, without nginx between. If the behavior disappears you know its something with nginx.